# COPY Command failure during docker-compose build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have executed the following docker-compose command and got the "cannot copy to non-directory" error.

```bash
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
```

Dockerfile

```bash
FROM ubuntu:20.04x

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y  
RUN apt-get update  
RUN apt install -y python3.8-dev python3-pip git-core 

COPY ./ ./ 
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
RUN python3 -m pip install setuptools==57.5.0 
RUN cd ./tools && python3 install_env.py 
ENV PYTHONPATH ./tools/src/ 
RUN cd config && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:   
    helix-build:     
        build:         
            context: $WORKSPACE         
            dockerfile: ./config/Dockerfile     
        image: build_sanity_check_image
```

Error:

```
[5/8] COPY ./ ./
#9 ERROR: cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/gafhkgbr6f6ixasuq4dk5cowk/merged/lib
[5/8] COPY ./ ./:
failed to solve: cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/gafhkgbr6f6ixasuq4dk5cowk/merged/lib
```

**This "lib" directory is newly added in my repo, if I remove or rename the directory its working fine.**

Anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Please show your `docker-compose.yaml` and `Dockerfile`.

Comment: No, please [edit] to include these details into original post, it is completely unreadable...

Comment: Try with COPY . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you use `WORKDIR` first, that would be solved.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04x

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y  
RUN apt-get update  
RUN apt install -y python3.8-dev python3-pip git-core 

###
WORKDIR XXX
###

COPY . .
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
RUN python3 -m pip install setuptools==57.5.0 
RUN cd ./tools && python3 install_env.py 
ENV PYTHONPATH ./tools/src/ 
RUN cd config && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Here are the [`WORKDIR` docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)